# how to use if else in array

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I want to use `if else` condition in array. while passing an array elements I am getting wrong data.

here is my code

```
print "Enter Item u want: ";

$i=<>;

@array=("coffee","tea","buttermilk");

%hash = map{ $_ =>1 }@array;

if(exists($para{$i})){

    print "available \n";

}

else{

    print "Not available \n";

}
```

even i am passing array items i am getting not available message

Answer (score 2):

The value that you read from `<>` will include a newline character. None of the keys in your hash contain a newline. Therefore `$i` will never be found in your hash.

You want to remove the newline from `$i` using `chomp()`.

```
chomp($i = <>);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems quite complicated to me to first build a hash, why not use 
[grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html)?

```
if ( grep { $_ eq $in }@array ){
print "available\n";
}else{
print "not available\n";
}
```